# Get changes to multiselect listbox selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox databound if not postback and items selected from a database (if applicable).  If i select new items in the listbox and postback, my foreach logic always sees only the original selection, not the changes.  Been banging my head trolling google for the answer.  Here's the code behind:

```
  foreach (ListItem li in lsb.Items)
  {
    if (li.Selected)
    {
      try
      {
        [sql insert]
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT: I should add the listbox is contained within and updatepanel

Answer (score 4):

Hope these will give you muse.

```
protected void MyListBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        listObject = sender as ListBox;

        if (listObjct ! = null && !CheckItemInDBorNot(listObject.Text))
        {
            // This item not exists in Db,
            // excute sql insert it into Db.
            Add(listOjbect.Text);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" />
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnPostback" runat="server" Text="Postback" OnClick="btnPostback_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code-behind:

```
protected void btnPostback_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= ListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i++) {
        ListItem li = ListBox1.Items(i);
        if (li.Selected) {
            try {
                string sValue = li.Text;
            // Do insert here

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```